# How to print hand touch in android

Tags: android, multi-touch

I was trying to print a hand touch on the android screen.
I try this code:

```
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
{
        int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

        for (int i=0; i<pointerCount;i++){
             Point point = new Point();
                point.x = event.getX(i);
                point.y = event.getY(i);
                points.add(point);
                invalidate();

        }
        return true;
    }
```

after that code I just print the array: points.
the results is just few points.  not all the touch area.
I trying to get all the touch area.
How can I do that?

Thanks 
Saar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of points available varies with the hardware, but in no cases is it infinite.

Comment: I don't understand. I get just 3 or 4 point. I don't Expect to get infinite points but at least 100 or more points

Comment: The number of touch points you get is a function of the hardware.  The largest number I know of is on the Samsung i9000, which provides up to five.  Until there's hardware that can provide an infinite number of points (or polygons where it's being touched), those are the limits.

Comment: ok thanks. I understand thata there is now way that i can do a app that paint all the tocuh area...